# Is that the best way to release SQLite connection in Java?

Tags: java, sqlite, sqlexception, try-catch-finally

I need a good way to close SQLIte connections in Java. After a few suggestion by other users I decided to add to my code a `finally` block to be sure that closing operation are always executed.

```
public static boolean executeQuery(String query)
{

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Global.dbPath);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(query);
        return true;   
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        try 
        { 
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
            return true;
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println ("Errore closing connections");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure that this is the best solution.

How can I optimize this for readability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments; nutshells:

- Separate the SQL exceptions from the reflection exception.
- Are your SQL exceptions recoverable? If not, throw an app-specific `RuntimeException`.
- Wrap up the connection and statement close exceptions in a utility method, yours or a 3rd party's.
- Don't short-change exception handling; dump the stack trace.

This leads to the following:

```java
public static boolean executeQuery(String query) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new DbException("Could not find JDBC driver", e);
    }

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Global.dbPath);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(query);
        return true;
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        throw new DbException("Exception during statement execution", e);
    } finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(stmt);
    }
}
```

(I'm using Apache Commons' DbUtils for its `closeQuietly`, it checks for null (yours didn't). Your own version might throw an app-specific exception as I do here with `DbException`. This wraps up all your DB-related exceptions into a single exception class, which may or may not be what you need.

Comment: Really helpful. do you raccomand to use Apache Commons 'DbUtils? or simply create my own class to do that? thanks!

Comment: Another question. I used your code but the compiler gives me a "missing return statement" exception. Probably I need to put a return statement at the end of the method outside all other block? thanks!

Comment: @Luca You shouldn't needed an additional return, all paths either return our throw an exception. I don't think it matters if you write your own or not, but if you want the closes to throw your exception, you'd need to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure a command is executed you have to put it alone into a try catch block:

```
    try { 
        stmt.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    try { 
        conn.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println ("Error closing connections");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So in my code the best way to do that is to use the code you posted in my finally block? thanks!

Comment: The essential of my answer is: Don't put more than one command in a try-catch block if you want to execute the all. Because in case of an exception not every command will be executed.